# SP Designer 2007 - Conditional statement order

Tags: 2007, designer-workflow, conditional

I've created a conditional statement in a SPD 2007 Workflow which has the following logic:

```
IF 1
AND 2
AND 3
OR 4
```

I want this code to be understood as:

```
IF 1 AND 2 AND (3 OR 4)
```

However it is being understood as:

```
IF (1 AND 2 AND 3) OR 4
```

due to the lack of brackets. If I was using a language such as Java I could write either 'if (1 && 2) || 3' or 'if 1 && (2 || 3)' depending on what I wanted.

Is there something similar I can do in the SPD Workflow gui to dictate how this conditional will be understood by my program?

Comment: Could you do `IF 3 OR 4 AND 1 AND 2`? I think that should be understood as `IF (3 OR 4) AND 1 AND 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

1. Create a string workflow variable, say `Test`
2. Set value for this variable `Test = No`
3. Now create if condition like, `IF(3 OR 4)` then Set `Test = Yes`
4. Now next if condition will be `IF 1 AND 2 AND Test = Yes` then `perform your action`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this :
1. if (3 or 4)
2.   if(1) and (2)

this should work as per your requirement.